# Sending a file via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, http

I want to send a file using `HTTP POST` request, the problem is that I can't do it - `post` and `files` arrays are empty on the serverside:

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>

let data = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", 'http://someurl.com/something', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

Why is that so? The file exists, data variable is correct. The request is being sent properly. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FormData object for send your file.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", data); // data is your file
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```